# C++ Two dimensional array multiplication table

Tags: c++, arrays

I am using C++ and want to do a 2-dimensional array. 10 rows and 3 columns. First column is(1 through 10).  For Second column, user enters his/her choice of a number from (1-10) resulting in a times table displaying the results as follows: In this example the user's choice is '4':

```
1x4=4  
2x4=8  
3x4=12  
4x4=16  
5x4=20  
6x4=24  
7x4=28  
8x4=32  
9x4=36  
10x4=40
```

I can't get the user's input to calculate correctly when using the for loop.

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can try this to get that output

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n;      //To take input
int table[10][3]; // Table
cout << "Input a number: ";
cin >> n;
// Generating Output
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    table[i][0] = i + 1;
    table[i][1] = n;
    table[i][2] = table[i][0] * table[i][1];
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << table[i][0] << " * " << table[i][1] << " = " << table[i][2]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: @cmrflorida You're welcome, kindly approve the answer and up vote it. Thank You :)

Comment: I'm new to this site. I absolutely approve your answer but where do I vote it up? Thanks again!

Comment: You don't have enough reputation so you can't up vote my answer, however you can accept it, check this link: [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Everything seems to be working now!! Here's the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include<iomanip>
    #include <ctime>
    using namespace std;

    void displayTable(int table[10][3]);
    bool testMe(int testTable[10][3]);
    void createTables(int testTable[10][3], int ansTable[10][3], int 
usersChoice);
    bool AllAnswersAreTested(bool tested[10]);
    void gradeMe(int testTable[10][3], int ansTable[10][3]);
    void displayMenu();

    int main()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int userInput = 0;
        int tableChoice = 0;
        int myTable[10][3] = {0};
        int testTable[10][3];
        int ansTable[10][3];

        bool tested = false;

        do
        {
            displayMenu();  //Display the menu of choices
            cin >> userInput;
            cout << endl;

            switch (userInput)  //Validate menu choices 1-4
            {
            case 1:  //Display a users choice of table
                displayTable(myTable);
                break;
            case 2:  //Test user on users choice of table
                cout << "What times table test would you like to take? > ";
                cin >> tableChoice;
                createTables(testTable, ansTable, tableChoice);
                tested = testMe(testTable);         
                if (tested)
                {
                    gradeMe(testTable, ansTable);
                }
                break;
            case 3: //Display a new table of the users choice
                displayTable(myTable);
                break;
            case 4: //Quit program menu option
                cout << "Program ending.\n";
                return 0;
            default: //Invalid entry
                cout << "You entered an invalid item number. Please enter a number from 1 to 4.\n";
                cout << endl;
        }

    } while (userInput != 4);

        return 0;
    }

    void displayTable(int myTable[10][3])
    {
        int num;    //initialize local variables

        //Ask the user what times table they would like to review
        cout << "What times table would you like to review?" << endl;;
        cout << "Please enter a value from 1 to 12 > \n";
        cout << "\n";
        cin >> num;
        cout << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
        myTable[i][0] = i + 1;
        myTable[i][1] = num;
        myTable[i][2] = myTable[i][0] * myTable[i][1];
        }
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
            cout << setw(3)<< myTable[i][0] << " * " << myTable[i][1] << " = " << myTable[i][2] << endl;
            }
        cout << endl;
    }

    void createTables(int testTable[10][3], int ansTable[10][3], int usersChoice)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            testTable[i][0] = i + 1;
            testTable[i][1] = usersChoice;
            testTable[i][2] = 0;

            ansTable[i][0] = i + 1;
            ansTable[i][1] = usersChoice;
            ansTable[i][2] = usersChoice * (i + 1);
        }
    }

    bool testMe(int testTable[10][3])
    {
        bool tested[10] = { false, false, false, false, false,false, false, false, false, false };

        while (!AllAnswersAreTested(tested))
        {
            int index = rand() % 10;
            if (tested[index] == false)
            {
                int randomNum = testTable[index][0];
                int tableChoice = testTable[index][1];
                int answer;
                cout << "What is " << randomNum << " X " << tableChoice << " = ";
                cin >> answer;
                testTable[index][2] = answer;
                tested[index] = true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool AllAnswersAreTested(bool tested[10])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (tested[i] == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    void gradeMe(int testTable[10][3], int ansTable[10][3])
    {
        int correctAnswers = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            if (testTable[i][2] == ansTable[i][2])
            {
                correctAnswers++;
            }
        }
        int score = (correctAnswers * 10);

        if (score == 100)
        {
            cout << "You passed the test! PERFECT SCORE!!" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (score >= 70)
        {
            cout << "You passed the test. Your Score is: ";
            cout << score;
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (score < 70)
        {
            cout << "You did not pass the test. Your Score is: ";
            cout << score;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    //Display the menu function
    void displayMenu()
    {

        cout << "                         Multiplication Tables" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "        1.     Review MyTable" << endl;
        cout << "        2.     Test Me" << endl;
        cout << "        3.     Enter a New Multiplication Table (1-12)";
        cout << "        4.     Quit" << endl;
        cout << "        Enter a Menu Item > "; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int a[100][100];

    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<10;j++){
                a[i][j] = (i)*(j);
                cout<<a[i][j]<<"   ";
        }

        cout<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

There is how the output looks like:

[image: There is how my output looks like]